Properties of quotients of compact Hausdorff spaces [Reference request]
The following two theorems seem to be well-known:
Theorem 1: Suppose $X$ is a compact and Hausdorff space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $R=\{(x_1,x_2)\in X\times X|x_1\sim x_2\}$.  Suppose $R$ is a closed subset of $X\times X$, then the quotient space $X/\!\sim$ is Hausdorff.
Theorem 2: Suppose $X$ is a compact metric space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $X$. If the quotient space $X/\!\sim$ is Hausdorff, then $X/\!\sim$ is metrizable.
Can I ask if there are any references for these two results?
To be clear, I am not asking for the proofs of these statements.  I am aware that both results have been discussed on StackExchange. A proof of Theorem 1 can be found here: Question about quotient of a compact Hausdorff space, and a proof of Theorem 2 can be found here: Quotient of compact metric space is metrizable (when Hausdorff)?. But it would be greatly appreciated if I may ask whether there are any references for these results in published works that can be directly cited.  Thanks!

Theorem 1 is a part of Proposition 3.57 in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds (2nd edition). I don't know any reference for Theorem 2.

For metrizability, you can cite for instance Engelking's "General Topology", theorem 4.2.13 or 4.4.15.

Thank you very much!!
